# QT - QFileSystemModel on server-client program

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel, qfilesystemwatcher

I am working on a server-client QT project that allows to transfer files between server and client. Being a GUI project, I want to display the server's file system on client program, like a file explorer.

The question is : is there a way  to send the QFileSystemModel or QFileSystemWatcher from server to client, or to display the server's system file on client side? Thank you.

Comment: No. Invent your own implementation or use any existing network filesystem approach (e.g. SFTP or NFS).

Comment: One way would be to use QtNetwork in a dektop application to send the data through, and then you use these gui methods to display it on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to tackle this problem is to implement a serialization technique for your object(s). Once that's done you'd need to implement rules to exchange such serialized objects at the communication protocol level.

For instance, you could serialize a path like this:

```
file size - 8bytes; path flags - 1byte; path size - 2bytes; actual path - `path size` bytes;
```

In the file size field you'd save the size of the file pointed by the path, in flags field you'd save additional information about the file (eg. if it's a directory/file etc.;) in the path size the size of the path and in the actual path field, (obviously) the path.

For example, say I want to distinguish between files/directories by setting bit 0 in the flags field: 1 for files, 0 for directories. A directory path that holds 512MB of files such as '/abc/d/efg' would be serialized as (using `|` as field delimiter):

```
536870912 | 0 | 10 | /abc/d/efg
```

To serialize a directory tree you'd just serialize every file in in there and store the bytes in a vector. To serialize the vector you'd just add a prefix to it (say 4 bytes) specifying the number of files it contains; For example, a stream in this format:

```
2 | (536870912 | 0 | 10 | /abc/d/efg), (536870912 | 0 | 10 | /abc/d/efh)
```

Would tell me that I have 2 file path entries both of size 512MB, both directories one with name `/abc/d/efg/` and one with name `/abc/d/efh`.

Now you know how to serialize/deserialize a directory tree. To send it over to the other party I'd first prefix my serialized object with a unique message id type (so that the other party knows what it is receiving) and then send it over.

So in the end, given the two entries above, and assuming I prefix this type of serialized object with `0x00` the final stream would look like:

`0 | 2 | (536870912 | 0 | 10 | /abc/d/efg), (536870912 | 0 | 10 | /abc/d/efh)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try whether using QDataStream works with the model class. 
A really good example can be found here:

[YouTube: C++ Qt 85 - Binary IO basic object serialization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpmnHTM5qX8)

Comment: thank you for the answer...I did manage to save the QFileSystemModel into a file(server side), send it through tcp socket, but when I try to load the object from the file (client side) into a QFileSystemModel it crashes...I think QT didn't overload the ">>" operator for the QFileSystemModel ....

Comment: There should be an interface defining whether it is serializable or not - check if the model classes implement those or implement it yourself when subclassing QFileSystemModel. I see no reason why it shouldnt work like that as its just a bunch of bytes and a loader/saver code.