# How can I set a QFileSystemModel with information from another PC?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pickle

I'm doing a college project where we need to set up a dropbox-like service in a local network. I can do it easily in a terminal, but for some extra points I'm trying to set up an QtPy ui for it.

One of my widgets it's a QTreeView with a QFileSystemModel where I'd like to visualize the files and folders the user has saved on his "dropbox". The thing is, that the information and the folder itself are in another computer. I've tried sending the widget from one pc to another but you can't pickle widgets. I've also tried sending the 'self.model' and add it later but it didn't work. Any solutions? Here's the Widget Code:

```
class MyFolder(*form):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.client = ""
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath("./Archivos/MyFolder")
        self.myFolder.setModel(self.model)
        self.myFolder.setRootIndex(self.model.index("./Archivos/MyFolder"))
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addDialog)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do that directly. As stated by the documentation:

> The QFileSystemModel class provides a data model for the **local
>   filesystem**

- On the other hand as long as the underlying O.S can represent the remote filesystem as a local one, it is possible for QT to display it as a local filesystem with a QFileSystemModel.

Every remote filesystem that can be represented **locally** (using  protocols such as HTTP, (s)FTP, SMB (CIFS; Samba), SSH protocols and possible other sources),  can also be represented in a QFileSystemModel.

For instance on Windows you can "mount" a remote filesystem (for ex. by using using a SMB share) on a dedicated drive letter. In this case the remote filesystem is availabe exactly as a local one and it is transparent to any application using the mounted local drive.

- Another solution is to serialize the remote filesystem and un-serialize it on your local system as [explained here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904323/qt-qfilesystemmodel-on-server-client-program).

Comment: Thanks @Neitsa! Can you recommend me a guide or something to learn how to mount a remote system? I'll try the second option too and see which one seems better. Again, thanks, very helpful answer :)